# Valgrind reports conditional jump or move depending on uninitialised value(s), but I don't see why

Tags: c, unix, valgrind

```
const char path[] = "./folderidonthave";
struct stat stat_path;
stat(path, &stat_path);

if ( S_ISDIR(stat_path.st_mode) ) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

I still can't understand why Valgrind has a problem with this because it seems like the conditional variable is initialized.

Comment: Are you certain that `stat()` actually touches the pointed-to `struct stat` buffer even if the thing you're stat-ing doesn't exist?

Comment: because *stat* does not success the folder being absent ? you need to first check the return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the name of the path you are trying to `stat`, this seems quite obvious: `stat()` fails, and the `struct stat stat_path` that you declared remains uninitialized, therefore your `if` will branch on uninitialized data.

Check the return value of `stat()` for errors:

```
int res;

res = stat(path, &stat_path);
if (res != 0) {
    // Handle the error somehow.
    perror("stat failed");
    return 0; // Return something appropriate here.
}

if (S_ISDIR(stat_path.st_mode))
    return 1;

return 0;
```

Or, more compactly (assuming you want to treat an error the same as "not a directory"):

```
return !stat(path, &stat_path) && S_ISDIR(stat_path.st_mode);
```

Answer (score 2):

What if the call to `stat` fails? Valgrind will check this and, on the (likely) failure of the call, it sees your 'stat_path' as 'untouched' (uninitialized) data. Adding a dummy initializer list to the declaration will take care of this:

```c
    struct stat stat_path = {0,};
```

And don't forget to check the return value from the `stat` function to see if it succeeded:

```c
if (stat(path, &stat_path) != 0) {
    // Error-handling...
}
//...
```

Comment: @bruno Thanks - see edit. I have never actually used Valgrind, so sometimes I don't fully appreciate how it does what it does!

Comment: is ok => UV ;-)

Comment: Nitpick: the return value of `stat()` always needs to be checked regardless. Adding a dummy initializer isn't really needed: even if added it would be invalid to check it after a failed `stat()`, since `S_ISDIR()` is a black-box macro and you don't know which default value tests positive.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Fair comment! However, for my education: If the `stat` call fails, is it **guaranteed** that the given structure will be left completely untouched? If so, then initializing *all* members to zero (as the initializer I gave will do) should allow any field to be tested. But I would *always* check the return value, out of habit.

Comment: I don't believe valgrind checks function code return values. It does, however, do a really good job of keeping track of memory reads and writes. It knows if `stat_path` has been written to or not.

Comment: No, it isn't guaranteed indeed. That makes initializing it even more unneeded. Checking the value of that struct after a failed call is wrong in any case, you cannot trust it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks, again. However, I generally give *all* my non-POD variable an initial value (like in the code above), more out of habit that anything else.